# css - input field with inside button in wordpress site

Tags: css, wordpress

I am not very good in css and designing websites.

I don't get the rid of it.

I want to add an input field with inside button for submit. This is all inside a wordpress website as a shortcode.

It should look like this:

[image]

**HTML**

```css
.event_form_autocomplete {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #002652;
  color: #002652;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.event_form_submit {
  margin-left: -59px;
  padding: 14px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #002652;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
}
.event_form_arrow {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 17px;
  margin-left: -23px;
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control event_form_autocomplete" id="autocomplete" name="eventAdress" placeholder="Bitte gebe Sie Ihre PLZ oder Ort ein ..." onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" required>
<input class="event_form_submit" type="submit" value="" /><i class="event_form_arrow icon-right-open white"></i>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s5GVh/2953/

But it looks like this in

**Mozilla**
[image]

**Safari**
[image]

**Opera**
[image]

**Chrome**

[image]

All with the newest version.

Comment: i have looked at your jsFidlle , but it's taking full width same as firefox. PS : i am using Chrome 64.0.3282.186 on  ubuntu 16. Both in chrome and mozilla its the same. Am i getting your question that in chrome its not taking full width. ?

Comment: I am not sure. In every browser it looks not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

HTML

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
<input class="form-control event_form_autocomplete" id="autocomplete" name="eventAdress" placeholder="Bitte gebe Sie Ihre PLZ oder Ort ein ..." onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" required>
<button class="event_form_submit" type="submit" value="" /><i class="event_form_arrow icon-right-open white"></i></button>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.input-wrapper{
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #002652;
}
.event_form_autocomplete {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;    
    color: #002652;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-width: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
}

.event_form_submit {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 14px;
    width: 50px;
    background: #002652;
    color: white;
    border: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    right: 4px;
    height: 39px;
}
.event_form_arrow {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 17px;
    margin-left: -23px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's work for you `-webkit-padding-before:10px;`

```
.event_form_submit {
    margin-left: -59px;
    padding: 14px;
    -webkit-padding-before:10px;
    width: 50px;
    background: #002652;
    color: white;
    border: 0;
}
```

Comment: In Safari it works. In Firefox and Opera it is still the same.

Comment: @yfain: i checked with opera version 54 and it's working fine for me can you please give me your opera browser version.

Comment: You're right. Opera is working now fine. Seems that I have not clearly reload the page. But Firefox is still not working. Maybe you have some ideas?

Comment: @yfain : Again same for Firefox version 61 :P, It's working in my FF

Comment: I have firefox 61.01 (64-Bit) on macOS.  Looks like this: https://abload.de/img/bildschirmfoto2018-0789f9l.png

Comment: @yfain: As per your screen there is a placeholder font color is different than others.

For that you can use 

`input:-moz-placeholder,
textarea:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}`

Comment: use below and change opacity as per your requirement

`::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #002652;
  opacity:1;
}`

Comment: This should be correct? .event_form_autocomplete::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */ color: #002652; opacity:1; } - Is not working

Comment: It looks still the same.

Comment: I updated http://jsfiddle.net/s5GVh/2973/ code please check in firefox, chrome

line no.9